# Updating a dict value in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The assignment is written in the docstring by my prof:

```
def evaluateBallot (voterPreferences, candidates):
    """
    Using voterPreferences (a dict associating each voter with a list of
      candidate names ordered from highest to lowest preference) and
      candidates(a set of candidates still remaining in the election),
      returns the vote distribution: a dict associating the name of each
      candidate in the election to the number of votes that they received
    >>> result = evaluateBallot(dict(x=['a','b','c'], y=['a','c','b'],z= ['c','a','b']),set(['b','c'])) 
    >>> (result['b'],result['c'])
    (1, 2)
    """

    d ={}
    for candidate in candidates:
       d[candidate] = 0
    for voterPreference in voterPreferences:
       if candidate == voterPreference[0]:
          d[candidate] += 1
    return d
```

When I run the code I wrote, the dictionary does not update +1 for each time the candidate is a voter's top choice. I feel like the error is in my if statement, but I'm not sure what it is exactly?

Comment: Is that really your indentation?

Comment: your indentation is erroneous.

Comment: No, it is not really my indentation.

Comment: i would have expected an 'IndentationError' if that was really the indentation. Have they changed that in Python 3?

Comment: nope, the original indentation would not have worked in Python 3 either.

Answer (score 1):

If the data is like what you described in the comments, then I think

```
for voterPreference in voterPreferences:
```

should be changed to

```
for voterPreference in voterPreferences.values():
```

since what you want voterPreference to be is ['a','b','c'] but not 'x'.

P.S. I don't quite understand why the output should be b=1 and c=2. How do you want to handle with a if it doesn't exist in candidates but exists in voterPreferences? Ignoring it? If so you need more logic in your method to handle this.

**Additional**

By your comments it seems that non-candidates should be ignored when calculating the final result:

```
def evaluateBallot(voterPreferences, candidates):
    d = {}
    voterPrefCandOnly = [] # Just use list since we don't care about who voted

    # Remove votes for non-candidates
    for voterPref in voterPreferences.values():
        filtered = filter(lambda x: x in cand, voterPref)
        voterPrefCandOnly.append(filtered)

    # Calculate the result for voting
    for candidate in candidates:
        d[candidate] = 0
        for voterPref in voterPrefCandOnly:
            if candidate == voterPref[0]:
                d[candidate] += 1
    return d

voterPref = dict(x=['a','b','c'], y=['a','c','b'], z=['c','a','b'])
cand = set(['b','c'])
result = evaluateBallot(voterPref, cand)
print (result['b'], result['c']) # (1, 2)
```

Comment: I've made the changes, but it still doesn't update the dictionary? As for the output in the docstring...I'm not quite sure. My prof wrote everything in the quotes.

Comment: @kk.lau According to the result in the quotes, non-candidates like 'a' should be ignored from voters' preferences, so ['a','b','c'] equals to ['b','c'] in the example. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think you might be getting ahead of what I have to do for this bit of the code. The next function I have to write deals with the remaning candidates, so I dont think the filter part is needed for my purposes now. So aside from that, what I should do is make the preferences into a list and access it that way?

Comment: @kk.lau I am getting correct results by using .values(). What did you get after making the changes?

Comment: !!!!!!!! 

Nevermind, it works! I'm not sure what I was doing wrong, but I just deleted everything and recoded because I was confusing myself. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the assignment assumes the reader takes for granted a particular kind of runoff voting. And thus it seems likely the teacher is also implying that "each person will cast exactly one vote, and that vote will go to their highest-rated candidate which is in `candidates`"

This is a complete answer you can check your work against when finished, or if you get stuck for a long time, or wish to check your assumptions:

```
def evaluateBallot(voterPreferences, candidates):
    """
       . . . 
    """
    votes = collections.Counter()  # or collections.defaultdict(lambda: 0)

    for voter,prefOrdering in voterPreferences.items():            
        for desiredCandidate in prefOrdering: # go through each person's preference list
            if desiredCandidate in candidates: # if candidate is still in the running                    
                # then this person votes for that candidate
                votes[desiredCandidate] += 1
                break
        # it is possible that the person casts no votes

    return dict(votes)
```

Comment: it's clear that he's not there yet but let's not do his homework for him... he just wanted to get past the block he was having - i'm sure he'd figure the rest out in the end

Comment: @chees "She", actually :)

ninjagecko: I will use this to check my answer-- thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for candidate in candidates:
   d[candidate] = 0
```

After this loop finishes, `candidate` has the value of whatever candidate was last in `candidates`.

```
for voterPreference in voterPreferences:
   if candidate == voterPreference[0]:
      d[candidate] += 1
```

In this loop, we use that leftover `candidate` value, and only update votes for that candidate.

I assume what you wanted to do is check that `voterPreference[0]` is a valid candidate. To do that, we can check if the `voterPreference[0]` is `in` the existing `d`, and update accordingly:

```
for voterPreference in voterPreferences:
   if voterPreference[0] in d:
      d[voterPreference[0]] += 1
```

We can simplify this by using tuple unpacking for `voterPreference`, if we know how many items long it is, or by assigning `voterPreference[0]` to another variable. Also, your 3-space indent is non-standard; please consider switching to 4 :)